# Does Google have an equivalent of the Mozilla Developer Network site for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

I recently hit an issue where [iframe sandboxing behaved differently in Firefox vs Chrome for getUserMedia()](https://github.com/nfriedly/contentful-dictate/issues/2), and while trying to figure it out, I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe and it matched Firefox's behavior. But I couldn't find any equivalent documentation for Chrome, so I had to just experiment until it worked.

Does Google/Chrome have any such documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

You can occasionally find useful information on https://developers.google.com/web/updates/, although it's really more of a blog about new Chrome features (and deprecations), rather than anything approaching comprehensive, organized documentation.

https://developer.chrome.com/home links to https://www.html5rocks.com/ and https://webplatform.github.io/ under "Open Web Docs".

The former is again more of a blog/magazine but does frequently have useful articles, such as https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/ (although it didn't answer the original question).

The latter has been discontinued for over a year.